# Sencha touch datepicker and ios soft keyboard

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a fieldset with a couple of text fields and a datepicker field.

All works fine except when a textfield is in focus and the ios keyboard is in view. If I click the next (or back) buttons at the top of the keyboard, and therefore tab into the datepicker, instead of the datepicker being docked to the bottom of the screen it flys up to somewhere in the middle. I'm guessing this is due to the keyboard pushing up the webview and the datepicker still trying to dock to the bottom which is now halfway up the screen.

This happens in the simulator (see screenshot) and on my device.

Is there any workaround for this? Can I delay the datepicker from popping up until the keyboard has gone back down?

BTW this also happens with the Sencha Touch select field

Answer (score 1):

you may update the picker component code:

touch/src/picker/Date.js:

```
/**
 * Update by ZWD/gloot
 * Date: 7/30/2013
 */
onDoneButtonTap: function() {
    var me = this;
    var oldValue = this._value,
        newValue = this.getValue(true),
        testValue = newValue;

    if (Ext.isDate(newValue)) {
        testValue = newValue.toDateString();
    }
    if (Ext.isDate(oldValue)) {
        oldValue = oldValue.toDateString();
    }

    if (testValue != oldValue) {
        this.fireEvent('change', this, newValue);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        me.hide();
        me.inputBlocker.unblockInputs();
    }, 300);

    Ext.hideKeyboard();
}
```

and picker/Picker.js

```
/**
 * @private
 * Called when the done button has been tapped.
 * Update by ZWD/gloot
 * Date: 7/30/2013
 */
onDoneButtonTap: function() {
    var me = this, oldValue = me._value,
        newValue = me.getValue(true);

    if (newValue != oldValue) {
        me.fireEvent('change', me, newValue);
    }

    setTimeout(function() { 
        me.hide();
        me.inputBlocker.unblockInputs();
    }, 300);

},

/**
 * @private
 * Called when the cancel button has been tapped.
 * Update by ZWD/gloot
 * Date: 7/30/2013
 */
onCancelButtonTap: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.fireEvent('cancel', me);

    setTimeout(function() {
        me.hide();
        me.inputBlocker.unblockInputs();
    }, 300);
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
the setTimeout method can solve the question!
```